# How to locate links in a calendar table using webdriver and java?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I'm learning to work with Maven, Java, testng and webdriver by doing a self training course. I been doing great with all exercises until I got to the last one, I honestly don't know how to solve it. Let me give you some context:

> **Exercise description**: Open the site homepage and using the calendar(html calendar in a wordpress site), check how many days of
>   the current month contain posts, then access the first day which has
>   post and print the titles of the posts in the console.
>
> When any day in the calendar has posts, instead of showing the day in
>   plain text, the site shows the day number as a link that once clicked
>   opens the lists of posts in the main page.

This is a screen capture of how this site looks when I click on the day which has posts, in this case October 10th 2013: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGRO2.jpg

Like I said the site is a wordpress site (unfortunately can only be accessed through VPN so I can't share it), and I need to use the calendar widget which is a table. I was able to go over each row and column of the table and print each column's text.

**But how do I find if any of those days have a link in it and then having located that element how can I access it and print it's content (is this case they want me to print the titles of all posts created under that date)?**

This is the code I'm using to go over the entire table and print the content:

```
//Test Case 6
    @Test (timeOut=20000)
    public void TestCalendar(){
        HomePage homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
        homePage.Go(driver);
        WebElement table = homePage.ReturnCalendarElement();
        //Actual Month has no posts, so we select previous one which has 2 posts
        homePage.ClickPreviousMonth();
        //We Get All rows of the calendar then we get all columns and its data
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        for (WebElement row: rows) {
            List<WebElement> cols= row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            for (WebElement col: cols){
                System.out.print(col.getText() + "\t");

            }
        }
    }
```

I'm adding the HTML code of that page in case it helps you to provide some answers:

Follow this link to open a Public Gist with the HTML code of the page: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/599cd722b5c906808528

The following is the HTML code for the Table I'm testing:

```
<aside id="calendar-2" class="widget widget_calendar"><h3 class="widget-title">Posts by date:</h3><div id="calendar_wrap"><table id="wp-calendar">
<caption>October 2013</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col" title="Monday">M</th>
    <th scope="col" title="Tuesday">T</th>
    <th scope="col" title="Wednesday">W</th>
    <th scope="col" title="Thursday">T</th>
    <th scope="col" title="Friday">F</th>
    <th scope="col" title="Saturday">S</th>
    <th scope="col" title="Sunday">S</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" id="prev" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="pad">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3" id="next" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><a href="http://10.28.148.127/wordpress/2013/10/10/" title="What software testing is, It is used for:">10</a></td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td class="pad" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></div></aside>
```

**This is the last problem I need to solve to end with this training, so any help and orientation will be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Use a better CSS query to get the links of the calendar.

It would be something like:

```
td a
```

Elements TD with a link A inside.

Not much help without the HTML code of the page.

Comment: Thanks for answering @jordiburgos I've uploaded the HTML code to a public Gist so anyone can take a look at it. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/599cd722b5c906808528

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution, while i'm sure there should be a better way to do this. But this worked for me & might help someone else somehow:

```
// Test Case 6
@Test(timeOut = 40000)
public void TestCalendar() {
    HomePage homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    CalendarPage calendarPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver,
            CalendarPage.class);
    homePage.Go(driver); //this just navigates to the page
    homePage.ReturnPreviousMonth().click(); 
    //returns the calendar element mapped in the page
    WebElement table = homePage.ReturnCalendarElement();
    WebElement dayWithPost = calendarPage.GetFirstDayWithPosts(driver,
            table);
    Assert.assertNotNull(dayWithPost);
    System.out.println("We'll be working with the following day: " + dayWithPost.getText());
    dayWithPost.click();
    List<WebElement> articles = driver.findElements(By
            .className("entry-title"));
    for (WebElement article : articles) {
        System.out.println("Retrieved Post's Title: [ "
                + article.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText() + " ]");

    }



public class CalendarPage {

public List<WebElement> ReturnArticlesOnPage(WebDriver driver) {
    List<WebElement> articles = driver.findElements(By.tagName("article"));
    return articles;
}

public WebElement GetFirstDayWithPosts(WebDriver driver, WebElement table) {

    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for (WebElement row : rows) {
        List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (WebElement col : cols) {
            try {
                if (col.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href") != null ){
                    System.out.println("Day: " + col.getText()+ " has posts and was returned.");
                    return col;
                }

            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e){
                //System.out.println("Day: " + col.getText()+ " has no posts.");
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

}